# Data Conversion R

Tags: r

How can I convert `c(mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat,wt)` to `c("mpg","cyl","disp","hp","drat","wt")`?

I need to add extra double quotes to each element in the vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either

```
paste(quote(c(mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat,wt)))[-1]
```

Or

```
as.character(substitute(c(mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat,wt)))[-1]
```

Comment: Why do you use `paste` instead of `as.character`?

Comment: @Roland The `as.character` would be more appropriate.  Thanks